Powerpoint - Video Background - Across Slides
I have a custom background that I designed that has our logo w/ subtle animation, I have it saved as a MP4 Video File. I added it to the slide master and set it to autoplay.
It looks great but when I move to the next slide it starts the video file back at the start, Is there a way, and how, to keep the video background continuing playing across the slides and not restart with every slide?
